# Notify the calling function of a run time error in C

Tags: c, runtime-error

Is it possible to notify the calling function about the run-time error in C?
Or is it done only through returning some invalid value like -1 ?
Currently I am handling it like :

```
if (pBuffer==NULL) {
    return -1;
}
```

Basically returning -1 which is not a valid output of the function to signal that
There was some issue. Is this approach good enough? Is there a better way to achieve the same?

Comment: may be through `signal`s

Comment: That is the main way it is done — by returning a value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; in C, there are no fancy things like exception handling that other languages use. An error is usually signified with a return value like you suggested. A common design for functions that might error out is this:

```c
int could_have_error(int *out_result);
```

The success or failure of the function is passed to the caller via the return value, and in case of success, the result is stored into a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use `perror()` followed by `exit(status)` only if you want to immediately terminate the whole program after getting error. Status should be `0` for success while `non-zero` value for error(depending on its type). Usually for failure/error `1` is returned.

```
#include<stdlib.h> //for exit() 
if (pBuffer==NULL) {
      perror("pBuffer");
      exit(1);
}
```

Other way around, you can return error from a function using `errno` to get exact value of error. But this won't terminate the program.

```
    #include<errno.h> //for errno
    if (pBuffer==NULL) {
              perror("pBuffer");
              return errno;
        }
```

Also you need to catch error where it affects `pBuffer` like failure of `read()`,`fgets()`, etc.

Comment: `exit()` provides little chance the error can be handled by the caller....

Comment: Yes, I agree. I think the question is incomplete.It doesn't define if the calling function belongs to same program. If that's the case then using `return` is  best.`exit()` is useful only if the user wants to force terminate the program after that condition occurs "irrespective of function where it's called".

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, error conditions are noticed by the return value. A typical example (on Linux at least) is [fopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) or [calloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/calloc.3.html) or [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) or [fscanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) or [getpwnam(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html) (or [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)...)

In *some* cases, error conditions could be signaled by using non-local [longjmp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html), with a *previous* `setjmp` having being called.

But use that carefully. You could need need to release every resources allocated (e.g. `malloc`-ed or `fopen`-ed) in between.

Also notice that `setjmp`/`longjmp` makes your code unreadable, so has to be used rarely.

If you mix C++ and C code, your C code could call some C++ function `throw`-ing some exception, which would be `catch`-ed by C++ code calling your inner C code.

In some programs, error conditions can be fatal. For example, many C compilers (some are coded in C) don't even continue compilation when some `#include` failed (e.g. if an included file is not found, they would emit some diagnostic, then `exit`). Other programs are `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` as soon as a `malloc` or `calloc` failed.

It really depends what your C program (or library) is doing. **You mostly need to *document* its behavior on failure or error cases.**

Some functions (like [getpid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) ...) are documented to never fail.